# ros2 throttle logs

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use logging statements like the following:

RCLCPP_INFO_THROTTLE(...)

in my code (C++, ROS2 Eloquent).  I am used to the ROS1 syntax in which you specify a duration (as a float or double) and the print statement gets printed every so often.  I found the code documentation for these here:

http://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/logging_8hpp.html

Here's what I tried in my code:

RCLCPP_INFO_THROTTLE(this->get_logger(), this->get_clock(), std::chrono::seconds(10), "Print statement here");

I am not clear on what to pass in for the clock and duration arguments.  Are these supposed to be std::chrono clock/duration or rcpcpp::clock?  I'm finding the documentation of clocks in ROS2 in general to be confusing and haven't found a good tutorial.  Any help would be appreciated (I'm going to do my own throttling for now because this is proving difficult).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352364/ros2-throttle-logs/) by [Neil Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/54919/neil-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was struggling with exactly this also this morning and I found the following to work (assuming `this` is a `rclcpp::Node`):

```
auto& clk = *this->get_clock();
RCLCPP_INFO_THROTTLE(this->get_logger(),
                     clk,
                     5000,
                     "Hello world");
```

---

**clock argument**

The source of `RCLCPP_INFO_THROTTLE`: http://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rclcpp/logging_8hpp.html#a53cee4093804b13f31cb1516087400eb

You can see here that the clock argument is used in a lambda capture and then inside the lambda. Due to this, the macro evaluation will result in `this->get_clock()`, which is not valid. As a workaround, I store the actual `Clock` (not the `Clock::SharedPtr`) in the `clk` variable and pass that along.

**duration argument**

2 levels deeper you can find the usage of `duration`: http://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rcutils/logging__macros_8h.html#ae33a3cea9859fb46168396b09a7514b5

Here you can see that the duration is converted to the standard rcutils_duration_value_t using the macro `RCUTILS_MS_TO_NS`, which is a multiplication by `1000LL * 1000LL`. So 5000 means 5000 milliseconds.

---

Originally posted by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) with karma: 247 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/54919/neil-johnson/) on 2020-05-15**:
Thanks for getting back to me so quickly! Your recommendation works great. Is there a good place to add this documentation? We want to adopt ROS2, but there are a lot of convenience functions and capabilities that we were used to using in ROS1 that are a lot less convenient in ROS2 (ros::Time and throttling among them). If all users have to dig into the source code that deep to get things working, I think it's going to be pretty discouraging to new users (and old users who aren't ready to adopt the new ways of C++11/14, etc).

**Comment by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on 2020-05-25**:
Not sure about where to add this in documentation.

Regarding the C++11/14 aspect: I would recommend anyone to jump to C++14 or even C++17 as soon as possible, as it brings a lot of new functionality that just works great out of the box. I find cppreference.com a great resource for making the step.